# Multithreading using queues in django + uWSGI

Tags: python, django, multithreading, uwsgi

I am struggling to make Python standard queues work in uWSGI master.

Sample code:

```
import queue, threading, time
from django.apps import AppConfig

my_queue = queue.Queue()

class MyApp(AppConfig):
    def ready(self):
        thread1 = threading.Thread(target=process_queue, args=())
        thread1.daemon = True
        thread1.start()

        thread2 = threading.Thread(target=poll, args=())
        thread2.daemon = True
        thread2.start()

def poll():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        logging.info("Polling works every time")


def process_queue():
    while True:
        logging.info("I get here")
        email = my_queue.get(block=True, timeout=None)
        logging.info("I NEVER GET here. **I would like to get here**")

def put():
    # I call this from the django views on requests
    my_queue.put("1")
```

Both threads start. Thread 2 prints at regular intervals as expected. Thread 1 waits on the queue forever, even though I add to it from main thread (As part of Django requests, inside the views)

My uWSGI config:

```
[uwsgi]
master         = true
module         = backend.wsgi
processes      = 1
thunder-lock   = true
enable-threads = true
socket         = /tmp/django.sock
chmod-socket   = 666
vacuum         = true
```

**Notice that if I run uWSGI with `master = false`, everything works as expected**

Additional information:

- I am running this as a vassal. The emperor is not running as master
- I do not really understand pre/post forking in django + uWSGI. This could be an issue
- This works if not ran as master, but I cannot afford doing that

Versions:

- Python: 3.6.3
- Django: 2.0.5
- uWSGI: 2.0.17

I opened this issue as well https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/1860

Comment: Background task should not be run in the WSGI app. Implement them as a management command. Or use a system like celery.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @KlausD. However, this does not solve the underlying issue. I do not have the luxury of changing the architecture yet, this is a stripped down example of a more complex app.

Comment: WSGI applications are not designed to run extra threads in them, so your archticture is the cause of your observation. The symptoms might differ depending on the WSGI server settings.